# Can と imply と言わんばかりに?

Tags: grammar, particle-と

I can't understand how と is used in the bolded sentence below. Does と in that sentence imply と言って ("Understand it please - said ボイスくん looking at me."), or does it imply と言わんばかりに ("ボイスくん was looking at me as if saying 'understand it'.")?

For reference, that last sentence is a narration, and not part of the dialogue.

> ボイス「死体も何も、殺される瞬間、俺はその場にいた」
>
> ボイス「忘れやしない」
>
> ボイス「ーー絶対に」
>
> 思い出したくもない、と言わんばかりに表情を歪め、その感情を吐露する。
>
> 僕「・・・・・・殺されたのですか？」
>
> それは、また。ご愁傷様ですとでも言うべきなのだろうかーーと悩んでいると
>
> ボイス「ーー三年前の山賊たちがやらかした傷痕は、今の俺達の心を蝕んでいるんだ。それを治すことができるのは先生だけ」
>
> **察してくれよ、とボイスくんが僕を見る。**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 「[察]{さっ}してくれよ、とボイスくんが[僕]{ぼく}を[見]{み}る。」
>
> Does と in that sentence imply と言って ("Understand it please - said ボイスくん looking at me.")?

No, it does not imply that.  If ボイスくん had actually said 「察してくれよ」 out loud to 僕, the author surely would have expressed that using a direct quote just like all those direct quotes from the beginning.

Besides, the combination of 「察してくれよ (Please guess [how I am feeling].)」 and 「僕を見る (He looked at me)」 should tell us that there were no words being spoken during that moment.

> or does it imply と言わんばかりに ("ボイスくん was looking at me as if saying 'understand it'.")?

Yes, it does.  Other possibilities include 「とでも言いたげに」、「とでも言うように」, etc.

The reason that the author just used 「と」 could be the fact that s/he used 「と言わんばかりに」 only a few lines before.